# C# WPF Reuseable combobox populate method

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have the following code to populate a ConboBox using a LookupItem data service.  Is there any way to make this code reuseable by being able to pass in the Model/Class name and the 'Name' property which is used for the DisplayMember, i.e. in the case below 'GradeName'.

Many Thanks.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<LookupItem>> GetGradeLookupAsync()
        {
            using (var ctx = _contextCreator())
            {
                return await ctx.Grades.AsNoTracking()
                    .Select(g =>
                    new LookupItem
                    {
                        Id = g.Id,
                        DisplayMember = g.GradeName

                    })
                    .ToListAsync();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with a generic method. Something like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<LookupItem>> GetGradeLookupAsync<T>(
    Func<MyContext, IList<T>> dbSet,
    Func<T, int> idProperty,
    Func<T, string> nameProperty)
{
    using (var ctx = _contextCreator())
    {
        var set = dbSet(ctx);
        return set
            .Select(g =>
                new LookupItem
                {
                    Id = idProperty(g),
                    DisplayMember = nameProperty(g)

                });
        .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

**Sample usage:**

```
await GetGradeLookupAsync(ctx => ctx.Grades, g => g.Id, g => g.GradeName);
```